# Pegar um objeto de uma lista por referência e não por posição

Tags: c#

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso criar uma lista de objetos em C#, mas ao invés de pegar eles por `posição ([0], [i])`, quero pegar por referência `[LacoAzul] [CorVermelha]`.
Tem como criar uma lista assim?

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Olá. Pode explicar melhor o que é que entende por referência?

Comment: O que você deve estar procurando é um dicionário, e não uma lista.

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem algumas classes do Framework que funcionam assim.

Você pode usar um [dicionário](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Em um dicionário não existe ordem. Você acessa os elementos por chaves. A chave pode ser de qualquer tipo - se for um tipo por referência, então você pode passar a referência de um objeto para obter o outro objeto do par **chave**-**valor**.

<strike>Talvez uma tabela hash (com a classe [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)) também resolva o seu problema. Assim como o dicionário ela também funciona com pares de **chave**-**valor**, mas é uma estrutura mais simples.</strike> **edição:** a classe Hashtable agora é obsoleta.

P.S.: se o objetivo é *apenas* saber se o elemento se encontra na lista, a própria lista genérica (classe [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)) possui o método [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx), que indica se um elemento se encontra ou não na lista a partir de sua referência.

Comment: Era do dicionário que eu precisava, obrigado!

Comment: O conselho do dicionario e' bom (e cumpre os requisitos do OP), mas nao concordo com a hashtable. A `HashTable` foi lancada com o .NET 1.0, mas foi *deprecated* com o lancamento do .NET 2.0 que introduziu generics. Basicamente, a classe generica `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` veio substituir a nao-generica `HashTable`. O seu uso nao e' mais recomendado.

Comment: @dcastro tem razão, vou editar.